# Topic Modelling Visualization using LDAvis and R shinyapp and parameter settings

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, topic-modeling

I am using LDAvis in R shiny app.

Here is the code and it works without errors.

```
# docs is a csv file with a "text" column, e.g.   
# docs <- read.csv("docs.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "NLP app",

  tabPanel("Topic Model",icon = icon("group"), 
           fluidPage(

             headerPanel(""),
             titlePanel(p(h2("Topic Modelling example",style = "color:#4d3a7d"))),

             #sidebarPanel(
             wellPanel(tags$style(type="text/css", '#leftPanel { width:200px; float:left;}'), style = "background: lightgrey",
                       id = "leftPanel",
                       sliderInput("nTopics", "Number of topics to display", min = 5, max = 50, value = 10, step=5),
                       sliderInput("nTerms", "#top terms per topic", min = 10, max = 50, value = 20, step=5),
                       tags$hr(),
                       actionButton(inputId = "GoButton", label = "Go",  icon("refresh"))
         ),
             mainPanel( 
               tabPanel("Topic Visualisation", hr(),helpText(h2("Please select a topic!")),  visOutput('visChart')))
           )
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Topic_Subset <- reactive({

    docs <- docs$text  
    nTopics <- input$nTopics

    # topic model using text2vec package
    tokens = docs %>% 
      tolower %>% 
      word_tokenizer

    it = itoken(tokens, progressbar = FALSE)
    v = create_vocabulary(it,stopwords=tm::stopwords("en")) 
    vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
    dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix")

    lda_model = text2vec::LDA$new(n_topics = nTopics, doc_topic_prior = 0.1, topic_word_prior = 0.01)
    lda_model$fit_transform(x = dtm, n_iter = 1000, 
                        convergence_tol = 0.001, n_check_convergence = 25, 
                        progressbar = FALSE)

    return(lda_model) # 
  })

  output$visChart <- renderVis({

    input$GoButton

    isolate({
      nterms    <- input$nTerms
      lda_model <- Topic_Subset()
    })

    lda_model$plot(out.dir = "./results", R = nterms, open.browser = FALSE)

   readLines("./results/lda.json")

  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to see whether it is possible to use width = "80%" in visOutput('visChart') similar to, for example, wordcloud2Output("a_name",width = "80%"); or any alternative methods to make the size of visualization smaller. Particularly, when I minimize the shiny app window, the plot does not fit in the page. My second question is: how can I initialize the parameter lambda (please see the below image and yellow highlights) with another number like 0.6 (not 1)?

[image]

Comment: Please try to make your code reproducible. Currently object 'docs' can not be found.

Comment: docs is a data.frame with "text" column (free text). The data cannot be available due to the privacy, but I can provide another data if it helps.